# Java api to get Microsoft Windows Special folders

Tags: java, windows, special-folders

I once found a nifty little library that used JNI to allow java applications on Windows to get the locations of various "special" directories on windows.  I can't for the life of me find it again...

In particular, I need to get the location of the "All Users" (shared) "Application Data" directory.

So, anyone have a bullet proof way in Java to locate the "All Users" "Application Data" folder?

It needs to be bullet proof.

Comment: The bulletproof way to do this the Windows API SHGetKnownFolderPath http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762188%28v=VS.85%29.aspx but I don't know an easy way to call that from Java.

Comment: JNA comes with a fairly complete set of standard API bindings, maybe that's what you mean? https://github.com/twall/jna

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You could use the following property in the environment:
ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\Documents and Settings\All Users

**Edit: This no longer works as of Windows Vista and newer.**

Comment: This is broken. On Windows Vista and newer, it refers to the `C:\ProgramData` folder by default. (cc @SvrGuy)

Comment: That's exactly the kind of non-future-proof solution the OP was trying to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to research Environment Variables:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#DOS_and_Windows
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#System_path_variables

The [System.getenv()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv()) method offers a list of the system's environment variables and it's included in the core library. Doesn't get much more bullet-proof than that.